# Sequelize hasMany and belongsTo in same association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When i tried to combine `hasMany` and `belongsTo` i got an error. While when i tried to remove the `belongTo` in the include, it works properly.

```
    include: [
        //hasMany user role
        {
            model: UsersRoleModel
        },
        //taxonomy belong to user
        {
            model: TaxonomyModel, as: 'job_title',
            attributes: ['title']
        }
    ]


    UsersModel.belongsTo(TaxonomyModel, {as: 'job_title', foreignKey: 'job_title_id'});`enter code here`
    UsersModel.hasMany(UsersRoleModel, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

Comment: Post what error you are getting when incluse belongTo associated model to query.

Comment: //No error
include: [
    //hasMany user role
    {
        model: UsersRoleModel
    },
]

//No error
include: [
    //taxonomy belong to user
    {
        model: TaxonomyModel, as: 'job_title',
        attributes: ['title']
    }
]

Error says "Unknown column 'users.job_title_id'" when I tried put together UsersRoleModel and TaxonomyModel
include: [
    //hasMany user role
    {
        model: UsersRoleModel
    },
    //taxonomy belong to user
    {
        model: TaxonomyModel, as: 'job_title',
        attributes: ['title']
    }
]